# In libre office, how to set a multiline label programmatically?

Tags: label, multiline, libreoffice

In Calc (libre office), I need to set the label of a button in a macro, with 2 lines. But everything is displayed in one line.

```
nb=5
button.Multiline = true
button.Label = "You are our " & nb & "th visitor \n Thank you"
```

The character '\n' is displayed with the rest : "You are our 5th visitor \n Thank you"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **& Chr(10) &** instead **\n**

```
button.Label = "You are our " & nb & "th visitor" & Chr(10) & "Thank you"
```